# Stackoverflow Exception closing Form

Tags: c#, winforms, stack-overflow

I have a problem in WinForms. I created a MDIParent-Form and i call a ChildForm from the Load of the MDIParent. And I want that if the ChildForm closes, the MDIParent must close and the Application exits. Thats why i wrote an event for the childForm in the MDIParent, so that if the ChildForm closes the FormClosed-Event would be fired in the MDIParent, but it throws a stack overflow exception. I know that there is a infinite loop, but I dont know why...

```
   private void MDIParent1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 childForm = new Form1();
        childForm.MdiParent = this;
        childForm.FormClosed += childForm_FormClosed;
        childForm.Show();
    }

    void childForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close(); 
        //{Cannot evaluate expression because the current thread is in a stack overflow state.}
    }
```

but if i use

```
  Application.Exit();
```

instead of `this.Close()`... everything works fine ... i want to know why...can someone explain??

**Update:**
I have tried the same without a MDIParent and everything works...but why is there a problem if I use a MDIParent

Comment: You have an infinite loop: if the form is closed by any event, it will tell the form to close, which will trigger the event again, and try to close again.

Comment: why does it work if I dont use MDIParent ??

Comment: Maybe when you call `this.Close()`, it calls close on all the child forms, which in turn calls `childForm_FormClosed` and that's your infinite recursion? I'm almost certain Memphy's explanation is correct.

Comment: If you close the parent, doesn't the children get closed as well? That would explain your infinite loop

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bit of a bug, the problem is that the child still is present in the `MDIParent1.MdiChildren` collection when the FormClosed event fires.  In other words, the FormClosed event fires a little too soon.  So when you close the parent, it will try to close the child again.  Which triggers the child's FormClosed event again.  Which closes the parent again.  Etcetera.  Event firing order is never not a problem.  Well, let's call it a bug :)

The workaround is to use the Disposed event instead, it fires later:

```
private void MDIParent1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form1 childForm = new Form1();
    childForm.MdiParent = this;
    childForm.Disposed += childForm_Disposed;
    childForm.Show();
}

void childForm_Disposed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();   // Fine now
}
```